# How to set chart's percentageInnerCutout property with ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

im using ng2-charts and trying to make the doughnut chart thiner but without success. also i want to put a text in the middle of it. please help!
this is the HTML

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart  [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"  [options] = "chart" >         </canvas>
</div>
```

this is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dounught-chart',
  templateUrl: './dounught-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dounught-chart.component.scss']
})
export class DounughtChartComponent implements OnInit {

  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail-Order Sales'];
  public doughnutChartData: number[] = [350, 450, 100];
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-inferrable-types
  public doughnutChartType: string = 'doughnut';

  chart: any = { responsive: true};

  // events
  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Html

  ```
  <canvas baseChart style="height: 100%; width:100%;    position: grid;
  bottom: 40px;"
    [datasets]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
        [options]="doughnutChartOptions"
        [colors]="doughnutChartColors"></canvas>
  ```
- ts

  doughnutChartOptions:any = {
  **cutoutPercentage: 55**,
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    fullWidth: false,
    labels:{
      padding: 15,
      fontSize: 10,
      usePointStyle: true,
      fontColor: 'rgb(143, 142, 142)',
      boxWidth: 10,
    }
  },
  }